# How to count small seeds of two different kinds in an image?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I have an image in which there are about 503 chia seeds and 4 black pepper seeds below:[image: seeds distributed]

I am trying to count both of them. I a familiar with counting one type of object using the size of the seed and divide it by the total area covered by them. This is a simple approach but it works just fine.

For the image above, I found the grain size using the thresholding approach and it turns out to be 197 units and by using the below code I can find the total number of seeds:

```
image = Image.open('./shapes/S__14155926.jpg')
arr = np.array(image)
nseeds = np.sum(arr[...,2] < 100) / 197
print(nseeds)
504.58468309859154
```

The number is in ballpark and a couple of wrong counts here in there is no issue. However, how do I find the output classified as `500 small seeds and 4 large seeds` without having to train a CNN model. I don't wish to recognize the seeds, just detect and count.

Answer (score 0):

Both seeds are very similar in colour, which makes thresholding a bit challenging. Perhaps, passing the seeds through a strainer would be easier, so you can use your technique in two different images. If the seeds were nicely separated from each other, you could give it a try on [blob detection](https://learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/).

Comment: Is there a way I can hide all the chia seeds in the image and keep pepper seeds for one process and then hide all the pepper seeds and keep chia seeds for another?

Comment: I do not think so due to the points I commented on above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I find the area of all seeds

```
img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_bin = 255-cv2.threshold(copy, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
S=cv2.moments(img_bin)
S['m00']
```

[image]

and get that the area is equal 26607210.0 pixels

Then I cut of  5 seeds [image]

and find their area 175185.0. Thus one small seed has 35037.0.

Since a big seed contains about 8 small seeds ( in the sane way as above)  I get that
there are about 728 small  seeds and 4 big seeds approximatelly

Comment: Thanks for the idea but the small seeds are 504 in count. Thats a huge percentage of error.